# SAP business one and HANA studio

Tags: javascript, c#, php, visual-studio

Good day, I have a trouble in SAP. I have to make automatic update World Exchanges currency in SAP studio. I can't ceate add on due it too. What can I do?

Comment: You mean SAP B1? You could make a service using the DI API to update the currencies.

Comment: I have created DI API service and my Addon works but I want this addon works (update automatic exchanges) when I enter B1 client.

Answer (score 0):

Create your add-on and make it execute the method "update automatic exchanges" on start. From the add-on manager make the add-on start automatically. So when the b1 client is opened the add-on will start and execute your method.